# Смена даты создания файла в с++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

И снова с вопросом! Мне необходимо сменить дату создания выбранного пользователем файла. Программа компилируется, но к сожалению дата создания не меняется. Адаптированный под консоль код корректно выполняется и меняет в итоге дату создания файла... Кусок кода ниже. Скажите, в чем причина?

string naka = SystemToStl(nama); // имя выбранного файла, полуенное с помощью OpenFileDialog

```
LPCSTR lpMyString = naka.c_str();

SYSTEMTIME lf;
FILETIME ft;
OFSTRUCT of;
HANDLE hFile=(HANDLE)OpenFile(lpMyString, &of, OF_CREATE);

if(!hFile)
{
MessageBox::Show("ERRROR","Справка", MessageBoxButtons::OK);}

::GetFileTime(hFile, &ft, NULL, NULL);

    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &lf);

     String^ strok = "";
     unsigned short vert = 0;
   //  WORD years, mesiac, den, chas, minuta, secunda;

     vert = Convert::ToInt32(textBox2->Text);
lf.wYear=vert;

     vert = Convert::ToInt32(textBox3->Text);
lf.wDay=vert;

     vert = Convert::ToInt32(textBox4->Text);
lf.wMonth=vert;

     vert = Convert::ToInt32(textBox5->Text);
lf.wHour=vert;

     vert = Convert::ToInt32(textBox6->Text);
lf.wMinute=vert;

     vert = Convert::ToInt32(textBox7 ->Text);
lf.wSecond=vert;

SystemTimeToFileTime(&lf, &ft);
SetFileTime(hFile, &ft, NULL, NULL);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: Для начала, проверьте код возврата у `SetFileTime`. См. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime#return-value

Comment: И еще проверьте что возвращает `SystemTimeToFileTime`, там тоже может быть проблема.

Comment: Может использовать функцию `stat()` ?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, Функция Set и GetFileTime, возвращают не 0, а 6, т.е. работают вероятно корректно... А вот SystemTimeToFileTime вернула 0.. Как Вы думаете, возможна проблема в инициализации unsigned short vert вместо WORD (вроде это одно и то же)... Не могу посмотреть статистику ошибки..

Comment: @freim, SystemTimeToFileTime вернула 0.. Как Вы думаете, возможна проблема в инициализации unsigned short vert вместо WORD (вроде это одно и то же)

Comment: Если SystemTimeToFileTime вернула 0, то нужно проверять GetLastError. Разница в типах unsigned short и WORD - несущественна (это действительно одно и то же)

Comment: Функции WinAPI стандартно возвращают не число, а `TRUE/FALSE`. Вернула 0 - значит произошла ошибка. Теперь вызываете функцию `GetLastError` и получаете код ошибки. Открываете заголовочный файл WinError.h и находите текст ошибки по коду. Но скорее всего у вас просто в каком-то поле недопустимое значение. Я бы посоветовал попробовать обнулить структуру `lf` перед присваиванием, а не инициализировать ее старым значением. Обнуляйте командой `memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(lf));`

Comment: @freim, спасибо Вам! Я посмотрела все еще раз... Вообщем (я дэбыл) ::GetFileTime(hFile, &ft, NULL, NULL); и SetFileTime вернулись с 0... А код ошибки у них 6 - ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE... Я значит неправильно вызываю... Но как же верно? Я даже явно указываю путь к файлу: HANDLE hFile=(HANDLE)OpenFile("D:\myFile.txt", &of, OF_CREATE);

Comment: Судя по коду, вы у вас перемешан нативный C++ с управляемым C++/CLI (и фреймворк WinForms). Как насчёт использования возможностей .NET для изменения атрибутов файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по коду в вопросе, у вас перемешан нативный C++ с управляемым C++/CLI (и используется фреймворк WinForms).

Давайте всё упростим, используя возможности .NET Framework.

```
OpenFileDialog ^ ofd = gcnew OpenFileDialog();

if (ofd->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
{
    String ^ name = ofd->FileName;
    FileInfo ^ info = gcnew FileInfo(name);
    info->CreationTime = dateTimePicker->Value;
}
```

Из диалога открытия получаем имя файла, создаём объект `FileInfo`. Далее просто задаём свойству `CreationTime` новое время. Всё!

В данном примере я беру время из компонента `DateTimePicker` (подразумевается, что он есть на форме). Полагаю, его использование удобней, чем несколько `TextBox`. Но при желании можно получить числа из текстбоксов и создать из них экземпляр `DateTime`.

Опять же, для получения чисел я бы использовал контрол `NumericUpDown` вместо текстбоксов.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!!!

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в функции `OpenFile`. Эта функция может использоваться только с 16-битовыми версиями Windows (если вдруг найдете IBM PC AT с Windows 3.1), и возвращает она не `HANDLE`, а некий `HFILE` (который вы принудительно превращаете в `HANDLE`). Попробуйте заменить эту функцию таким вызовом:

```
HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(lpMyString,
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            FILE_SHARE_READ,
                            NULL,
                            CREATE_NEW,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            NULL);
```

Comment: Последний вопрос... Не буду больше.. Но ошибка:  error C2664: 'CreateFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'... Нужно конвертировать?

Comment: @Anna, у вас программа компилируется в режиме юникодных строк, то есть `CreateFile` ждет имя файла в юникоде. А у вас `lpMyString` это обычная строка. Либо определите ее как `LPCWSTR` (кстати, а почему она у вас не юникодная? непонятно), либо вызывайте `CreateFileA`.

Comment: Да, я вызвала CreateFileA, но Get опять возвращает 0............. ААА! Почему же на консоли работает?!

Comment: @Anna, а `CreateFile` нормально отрабатывает? Надо сравнивать возвращенный хэндл с `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Если равно, вызывайте `GetLastError` и смотрите что ему не нравится. Путь к файлу какой?

Comment: Спасибо Вам за то, что пришли на помощь! Если я указываю в программе путь к файлу 

              LPCSTR lpMyString = "D:\mmmyfile.txt";
тогда программа отрабатывает корректно, создает файл и ставит заданную пользователем дату создания... Это получается и если пользователь в textBox'e задал имя файла и путь к нему... Но проблема в том, что мне нужно, чтобы пользователь выбирал уже существующий файл и изменял дату его создания..

Comment: СПАСИБО, НЕВЕРОЯТНОЕ ЗА ПОМОЩЬ!!! Работает! Это счастье!!!